# Copy Views folder for Asp.Net in .Net5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

Many things changes from version to version in Asp.Net depending on .Net version. I have a project for .Net5 and I cannot get Views folder added in my build folder.
I've tried to add next lines to my csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The result is that I still don't have Views foler at debug, release or publish folder. If I try to run in debug mode I get an error of missing views:

```
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
    /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
    /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

This is my ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
        .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, o =>
        {
            o.Cookie.Path = "/";
        });

    services.AddControllersWithViews(o => o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter()));
}
```

Adding `CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory` to csproj changes nothing.

```
<CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>
```

There are some solutions for this on stackoverflow, but all about older versions like .net framework and .net core 2 or 3. None of them has worked for me.

- Just to clarify. I can get it to work compiling all projects, but I need to edit my razor pages with no need to recompile my application. That's why I want my Views to get copied.

---

EDIT: Adding a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation package and setting Razor RuntimeCompilation at services configuration ...

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

...you can edit your views while running your app from VS without recompiling (not checked). Then if I add `CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory` in my csproj I have editable views in my publish folder. The problem is that when I modify any view I get an exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find reference assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll' file for package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Reference`. No idea how to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new Core 5 app? You will have a WebApplication.Views.dll under bin\Debug\net5.0 (given that your app is named WebApplication)

Comment: Maybe I didn't explained it well, but I wnat to have the razor pages in my publish folder, not a dll containing the code for the views.

Comment: Why do you want that? What's the use case?

Comment: At this moment, just because frontend desing will be written by a designer who doesn't know very much of csharp and doesn't need to know how to compile or publish. But there are lot of situation where this option is needed. I like the posibility to edit some code at runtime, as you can do in php scripts.

Comment: Are we talking about modifying production code runtime, or during development? For the latter, we have `"ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try to inspect newly created empty project

`dotnet new webapp --razor-runtime-compilation`

it will create the following project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>false</CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Now check the *Startup.cs* file for `ConfigureServices` method:

```
  
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

     services.AddRazorPages();
  // services.AddMvc();  
  // services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
}
```

Here we see services.AddRazorPages() extention method being called, so we could expect Razor Views functionality while calling `services.AddControllersWithViews()`

To summarize, adding nuget package reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` and calling `services.AddControllersWithViews` or `services.AddMvc` should add support for Razor views into the project.

Also configuring your views location is like calling:

```
 services.AddControllersWithViews()
         .AddRazorOptions(options =>
         {
                options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/{0}.cshtml");
         });
```

Checking the sources: [https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs,27](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs,176):

```
 public static IMvcBuilder AddMvc(this IServiceCollection services)
 {
     if (services == null)
     {
       throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
     }
 
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            return services.AddRazorPages();
 }
```

Comment: Useful link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation

Comment: I editted my question. Now I can get my views in my build folder but if I modify any view I get an Exception : `System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find reference assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll' file for package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Reference`

Comment: Is there any progress sir? @Antonio

Comment: No, sir. I can get my views in my publish folder but I cannot modify them whitout having an exception.

Comment: @AntonioRodríguez check my additional answer

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that when I modify any view I get an exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find reference assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll' file for package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Reference. No idea how to solve it.

Having
`<CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>false</CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>`
the issue of missing assembly `'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'` reference  was reproduced after running application from the published (`dotnet publish`) folder, and trying making changes the Views.

After reverting `<CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>`  the issue had gone.

Here is my `.csproj` that should work properly with `dotnet publish`

```
 
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>
    <CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>
    <CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>       
    <PreserveCompilationReferences>true</PreserveCompilationReferences>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="5.0.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
   <KnownFrameworkReference Update="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App">
     <TargetingPackVersion>5.0.0</TargetingPackVersion>
   </KnownFrameworkReference>
 </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```